# Is there an existing library method that checks if a String is all upper case or lower case in Java?

Tags: java, string

I know there are plenty of `upper()` methods in Java and other frameworks like Apache commons lang, which convert a String to all upper case.

Are there any common libraries that provide a method like `isUpper(String s)` and `isLower(String s)`, to check if all the characters in the String are upper or lower case?

EDIT:

Many good answers about converting to Upper and comparing to this. I guess I should have been a bit more specific, and said that I already had thought of that, but I was hoping to be able to use an existing method for this.

Good comment about possible inclusion of this in apache.commons.lang.StringUtils.
Someone has even submitted a patch (20090310). Hopefully we will see this soon.
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LANG-471

EDIT:

What I needed this method for, was to capitalize names of hotels that sometimes came in all uppercase. I only wanted to capitalize them if they were all lower or upper case.
I did run in to the problems with non letter chars mentioned in some of the posts, and ended up doing something like this:

```
private static boolean isAllUpper(String s) {
    for(char c : s.toCharArray()) {
       if(Character.isLetter(c) && Character.isLowerCase(c)) {
           return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

This discussion and differing solutions (with different problems), clearly shows that there is a need for a good solid isAllUpper(String s) method in commons.lang

Until then I guess that the `myString.toUpperCase().equals(myString)` is the best way to go.

Comment: have a look @ https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LANG-471 to follow whether it will be added in apache commons one day

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Guava's [CharMatchers](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/StringsExplained#charmatcher) tend to offer very expressive and efficient solutions to this kind of problem.

```
CharMatcher.javaUpperCase().matchesAllOf("AAA"); // true
CharMatcher.javaUpperCase().matchesAllOf("A SENTENCE"); // false
CharMatcher.javaUpperCase().or(CharMatcher.whitespace()).matchesAllOf("A SENTENCE"); // true
CharMatcher.javaUpperCase().or(CharMatcher.javaLetter().negate()).matchesAllOf("A SENTENCE"); // true
CharMatcher.javaLowerCase().matchesNoneOf("A SENTENCE"); // true
```

A static import for `com.google.common.base.CharMatcher.*` can help make these more succinct.

```
javaLowerCase().matchesNoneOf("A SENTENCE"); // true
```

Comment: All of these are since Guava 24 deprecated.

Comment: @kaba713 good call-out. The Guava developers now recommend using ICU4J for its superior unicode support. None of the answers on this page acknowledge surrogate pairs. Please write an answer which uses ICU4J, I can't figure out the API!

Comment: Guava is deprecated, this cannot anymore be the best answer

Comment: @MikeFHay You've likely found a solution by now, but if anyone else has the same question, please see my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67118483/1303158

Answer (score 33):

Now in StringUtils [isAllUpperCase](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#isAllUpperCase(java.lang.CharSequence))

Comment: "IT DOESN'T WORK FOR THIS STRING", and guess why :)

Comment: It works perfectly per its documentation; there's an example given:

 StringUtils.isAllUpperCase("  ")   = false

Comment: It's not buggy, if that's what you mean. It's just that it's very unlikely to be useful in natural language processing. It's also easy to fix (see [Simon's](http://stackoverflow.com/a/677592/147346) answer).

Answer (score 26):

This if condition can get the expected result:

```
String input = "ANYINPUT";

if(input.equals(input.toUpperCase())
{
   // input is all upper case
}
else if (input.equals(input.toLowerCase())
{
   // input is all lower case
}
else
{
   // input is mixed case
}
```

Comment: This doesn't handle any possible string. Instead this only handles a known subset of strings and I would assume OP wanted something that worked for any string

Comment: @sigmavirus24 Which case does it fail to handle?

Answer (score 19):

Not a library function unfortunately, but it's fairly easy to roll your own. If efficiency is a concern, this might be faster than s.toUpperCase().equals(s) because it can bail out early.

```
public static boolean isUpperCase(String s)
{
    for (int i=0; i<s.length(); i++)
    {
        if (!Character.isUpperCase(s.charAt(i)))
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

**Edit:** As other posters and commenters have noted, we need to consider the behaviour when the string contains non-letter characters: should isUpperCase("HELLO1") return true or false? The function above will return false because '1' is not an upper case character, but this is possibly not the behaviour you want. An alternative definition which would return true in this case would be:

```
public static boolean isUpperCase2(String s)
{
    for (int i=0; i<s.length(); i++)
    {
        if (Character.isLowerCase(s.charAt(i)))
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: great little function, love it!

Comment: +1 `isUpperCase2` should be the accepted answer. The current answer of `StringUtils.isAllUpperCase` fails for obviously uppercase natural language sentences such us "WON'T WORK", because `'` is not an upper case character.

Comment: The 2nd method above should more properly be called `isNotPartiallyLowerCase` or something to that effect because it is not including upper case it is excluding lower case.  So I believe "123" would be true because it does not contain any lower case letters.

Answer (score 7):

Not that i know.

You can copy the string and convert the copy to lower/upper case and compare to the original one.

Or create a loop which checks the single characters if the are lower or upper case.

Answer (score 7):

This method might be faster than comparing a String to its upper-case version as it requires only 1 pass:

```
public static boolean isUpper(String s)
{
    for(char c : s.toCharArray())
    {
        if(! Character.isUpperCase(c))
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Please note that there might be some localization issues with different character sets.  I don't have any first hand experience but I think there are some languages (like Turkish) where different lower case letters can map to the same upper case letter.

Comment: Note that toCharArray() will create a copy of the string. I suggest to use the old chatAt() instead.

Comment: In Turkish upper and lower case are as usual, it's just that the mapping is different from every other locale. Specifically whether "i" has an umlaut switches when switching case. The German eszet transforms to two characters when made upper case.

Comment: If the string contains non-letter characters (such as "2"), this method isn't very useful. It probably doesn't work very well with letters from alphabets that don't have upper/lower cases or supplementary range characters (32bit codepoints).

Comment: @McDowell The accepted answer, mentioning `StringUtils.isAllUpperCase`, has the same flaw. An English uppercase sentence such as "WON'T WORK" will return false.

Answer (score 4):

Try this, may help.

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

private static final String regex ="^[A-Z0-9]"; //alpha-numeric uppercase
public static boolean isUpperCase(String str){
    return Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(str).find();
}
```

with this code, we just change the regex.

Comment: private static final String VALID_CODE ="^[A-Z0-9]+$";

Comment: The given regex only checks the start of the string.

Comment: Just `str.matches("[A-Z0-9]+")` would be shorter and easier to read. And since `String#matches` implicitly adds the `^...&` to match the entire String, you also won't need the full regex `^[A-Z0-9]+$` suggested by @TimP (which you do need for your current code, since you're only checking if a String is starting with an uppercase, instead of being completely in uppercase).

Comment: It‘s better to store the compiled pattern as a constant and to just use that in your method, rather than compiling the regex for every call. Apart from better performance, you get a shorter method body and a more precise type for the constant (ˋPatternˋ rather than ˋStringˋ).

Answer (score 2):

I realise that this question is quite old, but the accepted answer uses a deprecated API, and there's a question about how to do it using ICU4J. This is how I did it:

```
s.chars().filter(UCharacter::isLetter).allMatch(UCharacter::isUpperCase)
```

Comment: I wasn't sure about whether to use `isUpperCase()` or `isUUpperCase()`. Both of them return true for the English Strings that I tried. If someone with more knowledge of ICU4J could clarify, it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you expect your input string to be short, you could go with `myString.toUpperCase().equals(myString)` as you suggested. It's short and expressive.

But you can also use streams:

```java
boolean allUpper = myString.chars().noneMatch(Character::isLowerCase);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use java.lang.Character.isUpperCase()
Then you can easily write a method that check if your string is uppercase (with a simple loop).

Sending the message toUpperCase() to your string and then checking if the result is equal to your string will be probably slower.

Comment: This requires more elaboration. A careless use of `isUpperCase` will result in flawed implementations. See the other answers (and their pitfalls).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution I came up with that's a bit universal as it doesn't require any libraries or special imports, should work with any version of Java, requires only a single pass, and should be much faster than any regex based solutions:

```java
public static final boolean isUnicaseString(String input) {
  char[] carr = input.toCharArray();
  // Get the index of the first letter
  int i = 0;
  for (; i < carr.length; i++) {
    if (Character.isLetter(carr[i])) {
      break;
    }
  }
  // If we went all the way to the end above, then return true; no case at all is technically unicase
  if (i == carr.length) {
    return true;
  }
  // Determine if first letter is uppercase
  boolean firstUpper = Character.isUpperCase(carr[i]);
  for (; i < carr.length; i++) {
    // Check each remaining letter, stopping when the case doesn't match the first
    if (Character.isLetter(carr[i]) && Character.isUpperCase(carr[i]) != firstUpper) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  // If we didn't stop above, then it's unicase
  return true;
}
```