# Checking if all characters of a string is uppercase except special symbols

Tags: java, regex

It's my first time to use the Pattern class of Java because I want to check a string if it is in uppercase. Special symbols like "." and "," should be treated as Uppercase. Here are the expected results:

```
"test,." should return false //because it has a lowercase character
"TEST,." should return true //because all are uppercase and the special characters
"test" should return false //because it has a lowercase character
"TEST" should return true //because all are uppercase
"teST" should return false //because it has a lowercase character
```

I tried to use the StringUtils of apache but it doesn't work this way..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there an existing library method that checks if a String is all upper case or lower case in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/677561/is-there-an-existing-library-method-that-checks-if-a-string-is-all-upper-case-or)

Answer (score 25):

You can check:

```
if (str.toUpperCase().equals(str)) {..}
```

Answer (score 4):

Just search for `[a-z]` then return false if it's found:

```
if (str.matches(".*[a-z].*")) { 
    // Negative match (false)
}
```

Alternatively, search for `^[^a-z]*$` (not sure on Java regex syntax, but basically whole string is not lowercase characters):

```
if (str.matches("[^a-z]*")) { 
    // Positive match (true)
}
```

Comment: In Java there is no need to surround regex with `/`.

Comment: In your first example you are saying to search for lowercase characters. Since are using `matches`, which returns true only if entire string matches regex you should use `matches(".*[a-z].*")`.

Comment: @Pshemo Thanks, coming from a perl regex background this is odd to me. :P

Comment: Yeah, it takes some time to get used to it :)

Comment: @Pshemo So `String.matches("stuff")` is basically equivelant to `$string =~ m/^stuff$/` as I understand it.

Comment: If I by `m` you mean multiline flag then is not necessary because in default regex (without additional flags) used in `matcher` `^` and `$` represents start or end of entire input, not just lines. You can change it explicitly using `(?m)` flag.

Comment: @Pshemo `m/` prior to regex in perl means `match`, `s/` means `substitute` and `tr/` means translate.

Comment: Oh, then you are probably right. I confused it with syntax from JS `/regex/m`.

Comment: @Pshemo Yeah `/m` in the flags (after the regex) is different to `m/` before the regex. i.e. you can have `m/^Some stuff$/m;`

Answer (score 3):

You could iterate through the chars. It has the advantage that you can customize the matching as you wish.

```
boolean ok = true;
for(char c : yourString.toCharArray()) {
    if(Character.isLetter(c) && !Character.isUpperCase(c)) {
        ok = false;
        break;
    }
}
// ok contains your return value
```

Comment: Won't downvote because it's technically correct but this is *really* not a very readable option imo.

Comment: @SweetieBelle then what would you improve about it? Go ahead and make it more readable if you want.

Comment: I wouldn't iterate through all the characters in this manner, I'd use regular expressions.