# How do I check whether a string is UpperCase or not in clojure?

Tags: string, clojure, uppercase

I want to check whether a string is uppercase or not. There is a function to check for a character but no function to check it for a string.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming that you want to check that every character in String is uppercase, you can use `every?` like this:

```
user=> (every? #(Character/isUpperCase %) "Hello")
false
user=> (every? #(Character/isUpperCase %) "HELLO")
true
```

Comment: While this is logically correct, this approach seems unreasonable to me performance-wise. A criterium benchmark I ran showed it is 50 times slower than the implementations I suggested, and I don't think you get much benefits for using high-level utilities like `every?` for such a low-level task.

Comment: @ValentinWaeselynck The approach is viable. The performance will be increased if you add the type hint: `(every? (fn [^Character x] (Character/isUpperCase x)) "HELLO")` . Now it should be comparable with your variants

Comment: I stand corrected, this approach is faster than I thought (while still the slowest of all proposed so far). It's still way behind StringUtils according to my experiments (here: https://gist.github.com/vvvvalvalval/0b6be04c0191cce6fa09bba8f821b967). Personally, I still favour the approach using `clojure.string/upper-case`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @ntlabs. For those coming later, note that this solution will return `false` when given a string with spaces (e.g. `(every? #(Character/isUpperCase %) "Hello, World!")` => false)

Answer (score 10):

For this kind of question, start by looking for the Java answer :)

[Is there an existing library method that checks if a String is all upper case or lower case in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/677561/is-there-an-existing-library-method-that-checks-if-a-string-is-all-upper-case-or)

In this case, my recommandation is to use [Apache Commons Lang's StringUtils/isAllUpperCase](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#isAllUpperCase(java.lang.CharSequence))

```
(import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils)

(StringUtils/isAllUpperCase "HeLLO")
```

If you want a solution portable across all platforms (Clojure, ClojureScript, ...) the best strategy is probably to compare the uppercased string to the original:

```
(require '[clojure.string :as str])

(defn all-uppercase? [s]
  (= s (str/upper-case s)))
```

Answer (score 0):

The cuerdas library for Clojure(Script) has a function upper (and locale-upper) which could be used to check for uppercase.

https://funcool.github.io/cuerdas/latest/#upper

```
#(= % (cuerdas/upper %))
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution is not, strictly speaking, one function that checks if the string is uppercase. That said, using the library [clojure.string](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.string) :as str you can, idiomatically:

```
(= your-string (str/upper-case your-string))
```